# How to bind <super> to Initiate Window Picker?

Tags: unity, compiz, shortcut-keys

If I map Initiate Window Picker to <kbd>super</kbd> it doesn't work anymore. I've disabled "Key to show the Dash, Launcher and Help Overlay" and I've tried both with CompizConfig Settings Manager and with dconf-editor.

I have to set it to a key combination like <kbd>super</kbd>+ any letter or <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to make it work, but it find it clumsier and I'd like it to work as I got used in Gnome.

Comment: I have no idea on how to do that, but my guess is that the Super key is just a modifier, like a Alt or Ctrl key, and not a "proper" key, so the usual keybindings would not work because they wait for another key to be pressed at the same time. Apart from this, why don't you just use Gnome? Ubuntu is moving to Gnome anyways soon, so if you are used to Gnome, trying to switch to Unity might not be worth it for the short time remaining https://insights.ubuntu.com/2017/04/05/growing-ubuntu-for-cloud-and-iot-rather-than-phone-and-convergence/

Comment: I thought the same, but then why does Show the Dash & co. work with just the super key? Regarding my switching, I've been using Ubuntu for two years now, I've tried Debian with Gnome for a week, but the only thing I found better is the behaviour of the super key, so I switched back. I think (and hope) Ubuntu will be heavily patched anyway.

Comment: As far as I know, setting some keys for some actions just don't work. I've had similar difficulty trying to disable Super+2.